# mitm threat with apt

Tags: apt, patch

I think* there is a recent zdnet article about a potential mitm threat-- but I'm not quite sure whether to take the advice or not.  Specifically, is there a hive mind that already knows the/some of the proxies that might be affected by not allowing redirects on update & upgrade commands?

https://www.zdnet.com/article/nasty-security-bug-found-and-fixed-in-linux-apt/

Also, I think what's being suggested is to turn off redirects, run a patch, and then update again.  Never having run a patch like this before, I'm cautious.  Don't see a lot of discussion of this here already.  Did I miss it?

Answer (score 0):

No such acrobatics are necessary. YOU do not need to patch apt. The Ubuntu Security Team has already patched apt for you.

If you are using Unattended Upgrades, then you *already* have the patched version of apt.

If you are paranoid about security (not a bad thing!), then download the patched apt package yourself from https://packages.ubuntu.com. Be sure to pick the correct version for your release of Ubuntu.

Comment: You may also be interested in [apt-transport-https](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-transport-https.1.html), though some say this adds minimal security.